# Maximum size of zipped file to unzip in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, size, unzip

I have one zip file that i want unzip .the size of this file is  70 MB. but application is crash when i unzip file. its run fine for 40 MB file.
what i can do to unzip 70 MB file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the application crashing due to running out of memory, or are you unzipping the file on your main thread - with the larger zip file taking longer, thus blocking your app for too long? The OS will terminate your app if it doesn't respond within 5 seconds.

Most unzip libraries will buffer the zip output in small sections and write to disk many times, so shouldn't take up too much in way of RAM.

If you haven't done so already, I would perform the unzipping on a secondary thread and see if that helps at all.